# Question on convex polyhedra - how would I approach this?

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, polyhedra

Question:

For which n is there a convex polyhedron with n regular (possibly different) faces?

How would one approach such a question?

(This question was one that I was given a few weeks ago as part of a set of other questions to solve for fun)

So far on this topic, I’ve learnt about Euler’s formula and a little on diagonals, but not much else.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel it’s not really stated, so I’m not sure!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thank you!

Comment: There is an interesting math question in here (assuming it has not been asked on the site already - a fair chance), but as it is written, it looks a bit terse. To some it may even look like an attempt to outsource an assignment. Others would like to know what you know already so that they don't need to waste time reproducing stuff. Whatever, we require some context. Please familiarize yourself with our [guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: And the question will be closed.

Comment: (cont'd) If I were to pose this question, I would start from the Platonic ones, and describe what processes producing new solutions from old ones I'm familiar with.

Comment: Why so pessimistic @ParclyTaxel? I think this question can surely be salvaged (unless it is a dupe) :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In my experience 90% of questions that are missing context or other details are _never_ edited to fix that problem. I was also going ballistic earlier in the day deduping combinatorics questions wrt a FAQ. But I have found no dupes for here and this question has at least been edited with a semblance of properness, so I will answer.

Comment: I apologise if my post was vague, I just did not know where to start from, and since my initial knowledge was trivial I didn’t think I needed to state this. However I have now taken this into account. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$-gonal prism has $n+2$ faces, so that settles the problem for $n\ge5$. The tetrahedron has $4$ faces and it is trivial to show that no polyhedron can have fewer faces. So the polyhedra you want exist for all numbers of faces where any kind of polyhedron exists, i.e. at least $4$ faces.

Comment: So simple (+1). I thought we need to embark on a task of figuring out what numbers can be obtained from recursively truncating the Platonics :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Teehee, my very first thought was to look up Johnson solids (there are only a finite number of them anyway), but of course I know my polyhedral facts. $\ddot\smile$